# What's the meaning of "Ops" in this ABE schemes performance form?

Tags: terminology, performance, abe

I am a Ph.D. student focusing on Attribute-Based Encryption, and now I'm reading the paper "Outsourcing the Decryption of ABE Ciphertexts", seen in Figure 1 below. It gives a summary of an ABE scheme performance, but I don't understand the meaning of "**Ops**."  I marked it in the figure below in yellow color.

What's the meaning of "Full Decrypt Ops" and "Out Dec Ops"？ Does it stand for decryption time?

Below is the link to the paper, maybe someone has read it.

http://static.usenix.org/events/sec11/tech/full_papers/Green.pdf

[image]

Comment: Ops normally just stands for "operations", as in operations per second on a CPU or - more likely in this case - total number of executions of a specific algorithm or primitive.

Comment: Thank you so much, a very detailed explanation, I am also trying to apply these scheme by python. Hoping there is more chance that can communicate with you!!  :)